# Errores y excepciones

Tags: python, excepciones

```
def get(rule_name,parameter_name):
    try:
        with open("parameters.txt", "r") as infile:   
            for line in infile:                 
                if line.startswith(rule_name.lower()) and line.split(":")[1] == parameter_name.lower():      
                    return line.split(":")[2]   
    except:
        print "Error"


if __name__=="__main__":
    print(get("aa","THR1"))
```

Me gustaria saber como puedo lanzar excepciones/errores para decir que un parametro pasado es nulo o no se encuentra en el archivo que abre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo correcto es lanzar una excepción diferente según el tipo de error que se haya producido, de modo que el usuario de la función pueda capturar los diferentes casos en bloques `except` distintos, para tratarlos de de distinta forma o al menos poder producir mensajes de error más informativos que un simple "Error".

En tu función pueden ocurrir distintos tipos de error:

- Que no se pueda abrir el fichero. Esto ya lo gestiona `open()` y ya eleva el tipo de excepción adecuada, sólo que en tu código capturas esa excepción y la "eliminas" cambiándola por un mensaje de error.
- Que una línea no contenga `":"` y por tanto al hacer `linea.split(":")` no exista el elemento `[1]` al que intentas acceder. Esto sería otro tipo de error que podríamos llamar "formato incorrecto del fichero"
- Que una línea contenga un solo `":"`, con lo que no existiría el elemento `[2]` que intentas retornar. Esto sería también un "formato incorrecto del fichero".
- Que el formato del fichero sea correcto, pero no encuentres dentro el `rule_name` que buscabas. Esto no es realmente una excepción. La función podría simplemente retornar `None` en ese caso para indicar que no ha encontrado nada. No obstante, si quieres tratarlo como excepción, ya que el error es "no se ha encontrado", la excepción más apropiada sería `LookupError`, que es la misma excepción en la que se basa python cuando intentas acceder en un diccionario a una clave que no existe.

Tenemos por tanto tres posibles errores en tu función. Idealmente cada tipo de error debería generar una excepción diferente. Podemos buscar entre las excepciones estándar Python a ver cuáles son las más apropiadas a cada caso, o inventar nuestras propias excepciones.

Si queremos usar las de python, para el caso anterior creo que las apropiadas serían `FileNotFoundError` para el primer error, `ValueError` para los dos siguientes (formato incorrecto del fichero) y `LookupError` para el tercero (no se encuentra el dato).

Con estas ideas el código quedaría así:

```
def get(rule_name, parameter_name):
    infile = open("parameters.txt", "r")
    # Si el fichero no pudo abrirse, python ya habrá lanzado por si solo FileNotFoundException
    # En caso contrario, seguimos:
    with infile:
        for line in infile:
            trozos = line.split(":")
            if len(trozos)<3:
                raise ValueError("El fichero no tiene el formato correcto")
            if line.startswith(rule_name.lower()) and trozos[1] == parameter_name.lower():
                return trozos[2]
    # Si salimos del bucle, es que no hemos retornado antes, por tanto no hemos encontrado el dato
    raise LookupError("No se encuentran los datos buscados")
```

Ahora, quien llame a tu función, podrá manejar las excepciones a su conveniencia. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código muestra como capturar juntas las excepciones relacionadas con el fichero (no se encuentra o formato incorrecto):

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        print(get("aa","THR1"))
    except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError) as e:
        print("Problemas con el fichero")
        print(str(e))
    except LookupError:
        print("No se ha encontrado la regla/parámetro")
```

En caso de errores en el fichero, la excepción es capturada en la variable `e`, que podemos usar para mostrar el mensaje contenido en la propia excepción. En el manejo de `LookupError`, en cambio, ignoro el mensaje contenido en la excepción y lo cambio por otro. Si la función generase cualquier otra excepción que no sea ninguna de esas tres, ya que no la estoy manejando el ejemplo anterior, causaría la interrupción de la ejecución y el volcado de la pila de llamadas. Si quieres evitar eso puedes capturar `Exception`, que al ser la clase base de todas las excepciones, capturará cualquier otra excepción. No suele ser recomedable hacerlo, sin embargo, al menos durante el desarrollo, para no enmascarar errores ocultos.